# 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.webkitURL.createObjectURL') in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

In my Javascript code, I'm trying to check on the blob URL created by an uploaded image:
`alert(window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(files[0]));`

In Safari, with this line, I get the error:
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.webkitURL.createObjectURL')`

To be sure, the files[0] is being referenced correctly. When I do:
`alert(files[0]);`

Safari tells me:
`[object File]`

So I know I have a file object being correctly referenced to - what should be - a correct WebKit URL referencing function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

webkitURL belongs to the File/Blob API, which is not yet supported in Safari (5.1.2) or mobile Safari (iOS 5.01).

ArrayBuffers are available in recent Safaris.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're focussing on the wrong element of that line. I'd double-check that both `window.webkitURL` and `window.webkitURL.createObjectURL` really exist.

Comment: window.webkitURL is undefined in Safari (works in Chrome, however). Any ideas why?

Comment: Well, it's not a standard, so I wouldn't expect it to exist anywhere but in the browser that defines it (Chrome). You might try the earlier names that Chrome had for it, `window.createBlobURL` and `window.createObjectURL`, but I wouldn't put odds on it. Good luck,